# How do I remove the rows identified in df2 from df1?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called df1. I then create a filter like this:

```
df2 = df1.loc[(df1['unit'].str.contains('Ph'))]
```

How do I remove the rows identified in df2 from df1? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `~`, not operand in boolean indexing:

```
 df3 = df1.loc[~(df1['unit'].str.contains('Ph'))]
```

Now, df3 is df1 minus df2.

Comment: It works! Just a followup: let's say I want to use an OR like: df3 = df1.loc[~(df1['unit'].str.contains('Ph')) | ~(df1['unit'].str.contains('Lh'))]  It won't work in my code. Is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: Check your logic.  Are you sure your want and OR or do you want AND. A lot of times, I easily get confused when doing (NOT) | (NOT) when really what you need is (NOT) & (NOT).